# не работает notifyDataSetChanged для listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Здравствуйте! помогите найти ошибку. не обновляется список ни в какую у меня.
перерыл stackOverflow, почистил свой `List<Product>` и записал новые объекты.
но всё равно не работает.
после ответа сервера:

```
public void updateCart() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "updateCart");
    cart = DataManager.getInstance().my_cart;
    setTotalPrice();
    products_list.clear();
    products_list.addAll(cart.products);
    lv_cart_list.invalidateViews();
    ((BaseAdapter) lv_cart_list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

код адаптера:

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private CartFragment cartFragment;
    private GiftsActivity activity;
    private List<Product> products_list = new LinkedList<>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public CartAdapter(CartFragment mContext, List<Product> products) {
        super();
        activity = (GiftsActivity) mContext.getActivity();
        cartFragment = mContext;
        products_list = products;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return products_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView iv_cart_item;
        TextView tv_cart_item_name;
        TextView tv_price;
        TextView tv_discount_price;
        Spinner sp_quatity_of_order;
        ImageButton ib_delete_item_from_cart;
        RelativeLayout rl_item_package;
        ImageView iv_current_package;
        TextView tv_package_title;
        TextView tv_size;
        TextView tv_package_price;
        TextView tv_package_discount_price;
        ImageButton ib_delete_package_from_item;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final Product product = products_list.get(position);
        String image_url = Constants.SERVER_HOST + "/" + product.image;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.iv_cart_item = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_cart_item);
            viewHolder.tv_cart_item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cart_item_name);
            viewHolder.tv_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            viewHolder.tv_discount_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_discount_price);
            viewHolder.sp_quatity_of_order = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sp_quatity_of_order);
            viewHolder.ib_delete_item_from_cart = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ib_delete_item_from_cart);
            viewHolder.rl_item_package = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_item_package);
            viewHolder.iv_current_package = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_current_package);
            viewHolder.tv_package_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_package_title);
            viewHolder.tv_size = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_size);
            viewHolder.tv_package_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_package_price);
            viewHolder.tv_package_discount_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_package_discount_price);
            viewHolder.ib_delete_package_from_item = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ib_delete_package_from_item);

            Typeface bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/Exo2Bold.ttf");
            viewHolder.tv_cart_item_name.setTypeface(bold);
            viewHolder.tv_price.setTypeface(bold);
            viewHolder.tv_discount_price.setTypeface(bold);
            viewHolder.tv_package_title.setTypeface(bold);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


            int stock_quantity = Integer.parseInt(product.stock_quantity);
            ArrayList<String> spinner_array = initSpinnerArray(stock_quantity);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    spinner_array);
            viewHolder.sp_quatity_of_order.setAdapter(adapter);
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(product.quantity);
            boolean isQuantityLessStockQuantity = isQuantityLessStockQuantity(stock_quantity, quantity);
            if (isQuantityLessStockQuantity) {
                viewHolder.sp_quatity_of_order.setSelection(quantity - 1);
            }
            viewHolder.sp_quatity_of_order.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    int quantity = i + 1;
                    String quantity_param = String.valueOf(quantity);
                    if (product.product_package == null) {
                        ApiClient.getInstance(activity).changeProductQuantity(product.product_id, quantity_param, null, null, null);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "changeProductQuantity package == null");
                        DataManager.getInstance().is_updating_cart = true;
                    } else {
                        ApiClient.getInstance(activity).changeProductQuantity(product.product_id, quantity_param, null,
                                product.product_package.package_product_id, product.product_package.package_product_value_id);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "changeProductQuantity");
                        DataManager.getInstance().is_updating_cart = true;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.ib_delete_item_from_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (product.product_package == null) {
                        ApiClient.getInstance(activity).removeProductFromcart(product.product_id, null, null);
                        DataManager.getInstance().is_updating_cart = true;
                    } else {
                        ApiClient.getInstance(activity).removeProductFromcart(product.product_id,
                                product.product_package.package_product_id,
                                product.product_package.package_product_value_id);
                        DataManager.getInstance().is_updating_cart = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            viewHolder.ib_delete_package_from_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ApiClient.getInstance(activity).removePackageFromProduct(product.product_id,
                            product.product_package.package_product_id,
                            product.product_package.package_product_value_id);
                    DataManager.getInstance().is_updating_cart = true;
                }
            });
            boolean hasPackage = isProductPacked(product);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "hasPackage = " + hasPackage);
            if (hasPackage) {
                viewHolder.rl_item_package.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                setProductValues(product, viewHolder.tv_cart_item_name, viewHolder.tv_price,
                        viewHolder.tv_discount_price, viewHolder.sp_quatity_of_order);
                setPackageValues(product.product_package, viewHolder.tv_package_title, viewHolder.tv_size,
                        viewHolder.tv_package_price, viewHolder.tv_package_discount_price);

                loadProductImages(product, viewHolder.iv_cart_item);
                loadPackageImages(product.product_package, viewHolder.iv_current_package);
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "hasPackage = " + hasPackage);
                viewHolder.rl_item_package.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setProductValues(product, viewHolder.tv_cart_item_name, viewHolder.tv_price,
                        viewHolder.tv_discount_price, viewHolder.sp_quatity_of_order);

                loadProductImages(product, viewHolder.iv_cart_item);
            }
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private boolean isQuantityLessStockQuantity(int stock_quantity, int quantity) {
        if (stock_quantity >= quantity) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> initSpinnerArray(int product_quantity) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "product_quantity  = " + product_quantity);
        ArrayList<String> spinner_array = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < product_quantity; j++) {
            spinner_array.add(j, String.valueOf(j + 1) + " шт.");
        }
        return spinner_array;
    }

    private boolean isDiscount(String discount_price) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "discount_price = " + discount_price);
        if (!discount_price.equals("0"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void setPackageValues(ProductPackage product_package, TextView tv_package_title, TextView tv_size,
                                  TextView tv_package_price, TextView tv_package_discount_price) {
        setPrices(product_package, tv_package_price, tv_package_discount_price);
        tv_package_title.setText(product_package.name);
        tv_size.setText(product_package.value);
        tv_package_price.setText(product_package.price);
    }

    private void setProductValues(Product product, TextView tv_cart_item_name, TextView tv_price, TextView tv_discount_price,
                                  Spinner sp_quatity_of_order) {
        setPrices(product, tv_price, tv_discount_price);
        tv_cart_item_name.setText(product.name);
    }

    private void loadProductImages(Product product, ImageView iv_cart_item) {
        String product_image_url = Constants.SERVER_HOST + "/" + product.image;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "product_image_url = " + product_image_url);
        Glide.with(activity).load(product_image_url).into(iv_cart_item);
    }

    private void loadPackageImages(ProductPackage product_package, ImageView iv_current_package) {
        String product_package_image_url = Constants.SERVER_HOST + "/" + product_package.image;
        Glide.with(activity).load(product_package_image_url).into(iv_current_package);
    }

    private boolean isProductPacked(Product product) {
        if (product.product_package != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void setPrices(Product product, TextView price, TextView discount_price) {

        boolean is_discount = isDiscount(product.discount_price);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "is_discount = " + is_discount);

        if (is_discount) {
            String old_price = (product.price + Constants.UAH);
            int i = old_price.length();
            price.setText(old_price);
            price.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.catalog_oldprice_color));
            price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            discount_price.setText(product.discount_price + Constants.UAH);
            discount_price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            SpannableStringBuilder sp = new SpannableStringBuilder(old_price);
            sp.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, i, SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            price.setText(sp);
            price.setTextSize(16);
            discount_price.setTextSize(22);
        } else {
            discount_price.setText(product.price + Constants.UAH);
            price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            discount_price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            discount_price.setTextSize(22);
            discount_price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
    }

    private void setPrices(ProductPackage product, TextView price, TextView discount_price) {

        boolean is_discount = isDiscount(product.discount_price);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "is_discount = " + is_discount);

        if (is_discount) {
            String old_price = (product.price + Constants.UAH);
            int i = old_price.length();
            price.setText(old_price);
            price.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.catalog_oldprice_color));
            price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            discount_price.setText(product.discount_price + Constants.UAH);
            discount_price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            SpannableStringBuilder sp = new SpannableStringBuilder(old_price);
            sp.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, i, SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            price.setText(sp);
            price.setTextSize(12);
            discount_price.setTextSize(18);
        } else {
            discount_price.setText(product.price + Constants.UAH);
            price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            discount_price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            discount_price.setTextSize(18);
            discount_price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы заполняете элемент списка только когда convertView == null. То есть единожды и в количестве, умещающемся на экране без прокрутки. Остальные данные просто игнорируются. Схематично код `getView` должен выглядеть так:

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // create (inflate) view
                // create holder
            } else {
                // get holder
            }
            // set item data to views
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно в адаптер новый массив передать и после этого обновить адаптер
сделай в адаптере метод

```
public void addAll(List<Product> newProducts) {
   products_list = newProducts;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

и вызывай так

```
((CartAdapter) lv_cart_list.getAdapter()).addAll(cart.products);
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после метода `getItem`добавить метод:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object o) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Чтобы не возвращать позицию.

Comment: студия говорит что нема такого метода в base adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
CartAdapter cartAdapter;

///
нужно создать и присвоить адаптер листвю
///


public void updateCart() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "updateCart");
    cart = DataManager.getInstance().my_cart;
    setTotalPrice();
    products_list.clear();
    products_list.addAll(cart.products);
    lv_cart_list.invalidateViews();
    сartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```