# Почему мой LIstView не обновляется хоть я и использую notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, listview

Метод SetDate() срабатывает после того как я в диалогфрагменте установлю дату. После должен сработать UploadData() в конце которого попытка обновить ListView, но че то не обновляется. Если массив предварительно заполнить чем то, то всё показывает.

блок try нормально выполняется.
и новый массив не пустой.

```
 public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.DialogFragmentListener {

    TextView Current_Date;
    String currentDate;
    public DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment;    
    String date;

    ListView listView;
    private List<ModelData> modelDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
    AdapterModelData adapterModelData;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);


        datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

        Current_Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Current_Date);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);


        adapterModelData = new AdapterModelData(this, R.layout.rates, modelDataArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapterModelData);

        UploadData();

    }



    public void onClick(View view) {
        datePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DataPicker");
    }

    // Метод интерфейса для связи с Активити из Фрагмента
    public void SetDate(String date) {
        Current_Date.setText(date);
        this.date = date;
        UploadData();
    }


    public void UploadData() {

        AsyncUploadingData asyncUploadingData = new AsyncUploadingData();
        asyncUploadingData.execute();
        try{
            rootObject = asyncUploadingData.get();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        rootObject.getRates().InitializatedModelData(); //создали массив с моделью данных
        modelDataArrayList = rootObject.getRates().GetArrayListModelData();
        adapterModelData.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```

**UPD**  Как я понял ошибка где то тут.. Как увидел в подобном ответе : 
Потому что Вы заполняете элемент списка только когда convertView == null. То есть единожды и в количестве, умещающемся на экране без прокрутки. Остальные данные просто игнорируются.
Но пока сам не понял, что поправить надо.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){



        View view = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);

        TextView name_rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_rate);
        TextView rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rate);

        ModelData modelData = modelDataList.get(position);

        name_rate.setText(modelData.getName());
        rate.setText(Double.toString(modelData.getValue()));

        return view;

    }
```

**UPD** Переписал адаптер согласно паттерну ViewHolder

```
public class AdapterModelData extends ArrayAdapter<ModelData> {

private List<ModelData> modelDataList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int layout;
private Context mContext;

public AdapterModelData(Context context, int resources, List<ModelData> modelData) {
    super(context, resources, modelData);
    this.layout = resources;
    this.modelDataList = modelData;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


static  class ViewHolder{
    TextView name_rate;
    TextView rate;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); 
        viewHolder.name_rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_rate);
        viewHolder.rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);




    } else{


           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ModelData modelData = modelDataList.get(position);
        viewHolder.name_rate.setText(modelData.getName());
        viewHolder.rate.setText(Double.toString(modelData.getValue()));

        return convertView;

    }


}
```

Всё равно не обновляется

Comment: Данные загружаются асинхронно. На момент вызова метода `notifyDataSetChanged()` они еще не загрузились.

Comment: Вы не правы. После вызова execute() ниже идет блок try в котором метод get получает уже загруженные данные. Этот метод блокирует дальнейшее выполнение программы до тех пор пока данные не будут получены(правда не знаю сколько этот метод (если он дефолтный) готов ожидать  до выдачи экспепшен, если данные так и не загрузились) Так что в момент попытки обновить список данные уже загружены. Дополнительно это проверил вызвав прямо перед обновлением распечатку новых данных в консоль.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697616 вот там дан ответ уже, но я что то пока его применить не могу

Comment: пробовал добавить в адаптер публичный класс с this.notifyDataSetChanged();  но толку нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле вы не обновляете данные, которые отображает адаптер, но заменяете объект-список в переменной активити. Вот что у вас происходит:

1. Вы создали переменную-список и под неё выделилась память на диске.
2. Создали адаптер и передали туда ссылку на область в памяти, хранящую список в активити.
3. После в методе `UploadData` вы в переменную в активити записываете ссылку на другой объект-список в памяти.
4. В переменной же адаптера всё ещё хранится старая ссылка на другую область в памяти где лежит другой объект-список.
5. Вы уведомляете адаптер, он смотрит на свою переменную, видит что в ней список не поменялся и ничего не делает.

Вам надо оперировать везде с одной и той же областью памяти. Вам надо не заменять ссылку (все переменные - суть ссылки на области в памяти), но изменять содержимое в памяти у одной и той же ссылке. Т.е. не присваивайте новый список, но изменяйте имеющийся:

```
//modelDataArrayList = rootObject.getRates().GetArrayListModelData();
modelDataArrayList.clear();
modelDataArrayList.addAll(rootObject.getRates().GetArrayListModelData());
```

---

И да - вызывать `get` над асинкТаском - извращение. При медленном интернете/большом объёме данных вы словите ANR. Делайте нужные действия с данными в `onPostExecute`. И вообще асинкТаском устарел. Используйте `OkHttp`+`Retrofit` + `rxJava`

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/469202/17609

Comment: ))) Вот что значит с qBasic перейти на java) Там то всё без ссылок) Спасибо за ответ, работает как надо. Да , кое что можно перенести в onPostExecute. До  OkHttp+Retrofit + rxJava   как нибудь доберусь, я два дня назад только AsynckTask первый раз использовал)  Долго еще мне до ваших знаний хотя бы по Андроид дойти) Вы вроде тоже не программист по профилю)

Comment: С описанной комбинацией либ запрос в сеть и возврат в главный поток можно сделать всего в 4 строки, без нужды переопределять AsyncTask и всё что с этим связано) Да, надо будет вникать, но оно того стоит 100%.Я уже 1.5 года как программист профессионально)

Comment: А каков ваш путь в программисты , если описывать так же как я : в школе почти 2 года qBasic и в конце VisualBasic поверхностно. Узнал циклы, операторы, научился писать сложные алгоритмы с кучей if (сейчас такое не приветствуется, а раньше это неизбежностью было). Потом 5 лет на другую специальность(нанотехнологии в электронике) и потом в свободное от работы время с большими перерывами Java. Понял что синтаксис как родной и вроде всё ясно. Взял андроид. и стал сразу писать игру, да еще без движка, потому что AndEngine некоторые алгоритмы были с косяками, а для меня  это были ключевые методы.

Comment: и я на эту игрушку (не код а вермишель получилась, я ведь в ооп не стал вникать, решил что успеется) потратил очень много времени. Уж лучше бы я уроки с стартандроид выполнял. Уже был бы опыт сразу на работу устраиваться.... Зато теперь ушел с военного контракта и пока учусь, делаю всякие тестовые задания с работ)

Comment: Можете описать на много компактней)

Comment: @Turalllb, началось с хобби - написал парсинг сайта (сеть - бд - список), потом другого, потом на работу устроился) Главное - постоянно писал код и тут сидел, отвечая на вопросы - собственно ответ на этот ваш вопрос я тут узнал 2 года назад, как видно из ссылки выше) Игрушку тоже вначале пытался написать и сразу понял, что знаний не хватает аццки. Я и сейчас не уверен, что мог бы быстро и хорошо написать) Я больше умею в клиент-сервер с точки зрения клиента)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69534/discussion-between-turalllb-and-).