# NPE при использовании паттерна ViewHolder, в момент повторного вызова в методе getView

Tags: java, android, listview

вот класс адаптера. Когда адаптер только инициализируется, т.е. запускается в первый раз, то он попадает в методе getView в условие if и всё нормально отображается. При обновление ListView, попадает в else . NPE выпадается на `viewHolder.name_rate.setText(modelData.getName());`

```
public class AdapterModelData extends ArrayAdapter<ModelData> {

    private List<ModelData> modelDataList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int layout;
    private Context mContext;

    public AdapterModelData(Context context, int resources, List<ModelData> modelData) {
        super(context, resources, modelData);
        this.layout = resources;
        this.modelDataList = modelData;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    static  class ViewHolder{
        TextView name_rate;
        TextView rate;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
        //     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);


            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name_rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_rate);
            viewHolder.rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate);

        } else{   
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ModelData modelData = modelDataList.get(position);
        viewHolder.name_rate.setText(modelData.getName());
        viewHolder.rate.setText(Double.toString(modelData.getValue()));

        return convertView;

    }


    public  void Refresh(){
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логично. Вы пытаетесь вытащить тег `viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()`, но я не вижу, чтобы вы в коде его где-то устанавливали.

В итоге у вас в `viewHolder` будет `null`.

Я так понимаю, вы забыли в `if` блоке установить тег:

```
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
```

?

Comment: БЛин точнооо.. Потерял это я . Изначально вопрос выглядел так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751837        Буду рад если там тоже увидите проблему.  У меня не обновляется ListView. Исходные данные , что есть в массиве показывает. А обновить никак не могу